# Saving canvas as image saves black area at top of image WPF c#

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, save

My problem is that I am creating images with increasing size black area's at the top of my images after saving them from a canvas.

Each time I save the image the black area at the top increases in size and a portion at the bottom of the image disappears.

When the image is created, it is loaded as the background of the canvas:

```
    public void LoadImage(string fileName)
    {
        BitmapImage bitmap;
        using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open))
        {
            bitmap = new BitmapImage();
            bitmap.BeginInit();
            bitmap.StreamSource = stream;
            bitmap.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
            bitmap.EndInit();
            bitmap.Freeze();
        }
        ImageBrush ib = new ImageBrush(bitmap);
        this.Background = ib;
    }
```

It is then amended by the user, and when they save, this is how the image is saved:

```
    public void SaveAsImage(string filename, Window parent)
    {
        Size size = new Size(this.ActualWidth, this.ActualHeight);
        Point point = this.TransformToAncestor(parent).Transform(new Point(0, 0));
        RenderTargetBitmap renderBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap(
         (int)size.Width, (int)size.Height,
         96d, 96d, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);

        // needed otherwise the image output is black
        this.Measure(size);
        this.Arrange(new Rect(point, size));

        renderBitmap.Render(this);

        JpegBitmapEncoder encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
        encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(renderBitmap));

        using (FileStream file = File.Create(filename))
        {
            encoder.Save(file);
        }
    }
```

What I am wondering is why the canvas or image seems to move each time I save it and the background turn black.

As you can see in the comments (the save routine was taken from another post on here) it uses the measure and arrange functions to stop the whole of the background turning black, however it's not stopping my image from moving / disappearing.

Any help / advice appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: My guess (if code is right), that could be some innacuracy due to coordinates. Try to use types with decimal point instead of `int`.

Comment: If I delete the line:
Point point = this.TransformToAncestor(parent).Transform(new Point(0, 0));

and replace:

this.Arrange(new Rect(point, size));

with

this.Arrange(new Rect(size));

it works, however I have added these lines in due to stop the canvas being re-sized and covering the menu at the top of the form.